# Aspose Words for Android: Get page count

Tags: android, aspose

I am trying to get page count from office document on Android using Aspose:

```
try {
    Document doc = new Document(path);//such as: "/storage/emulated/0/Download/Document.docx"
    //Get page count                                         
    int pageCount = doc.getPageCount();

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, application stops due to fatal exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.aspose.words.Document

I am using jdk-1.7 and I have downloaded aspose-words-1.12-android.
Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

luna kass.I think you have to install aspose-words-1.12-libs-android-jdk1x(5 or 6).apk.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, the issue was because I didn't include apk file into assets folder which should be done starting from 1.11 release. I just followed [the post](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsandroid/Install+Aspose.Words+for+Android)